# First Age "of the Sun" terminology

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, terminology

I saw a statement a couple weeks ago that the terminology of ages "of the Sun" in Middle-earth appeared nowhere in Tolkien's actual works and that it was invented by fans.  This seems plausible to me, since I don't recall ever seeing mention of the "First Age of the Sun," say, in *The Hobbit*, *The Lord of the Rings*, or *The Silmarillion*.  However, I cannot claim with a certainty that it was never used in his notebooks or letters.  So, if someone else coined the name, where did it first appear, and what precisely was it originally intended to mean?

It seems that J. R. R. Tolkien's conception of the First Age was generally that it was identical with the "elder days"—the times before the defeat of Morgoth in the War of Wrath.  Most of that period, from the descent of the first Ainur into Arda, was before the creation of the Sun.  Did the first person who wrote of the "First Age of the Sun" specifically mean the time beginning shortly after the Dagor-nuin-Giliath with the ascent of Arien into the sky?  Alternatively, were they being sloppy?  Or is the term older than the published *Silmarillion*, which laid out the early chronology of Arda?  (As a terminus ante quem, I know that "the First Age of the Sun" appeared in the first edition of *Middle-earth Role-Playing* in 1984, so it at least that old.)

Comment: I'd assume David Day is largely responsible for these terms, though I'm really not interested in digging into his garbage to answer this.

Comment: Google Books thinks the phrase "first age of sun and moon" appears in a collected volume of JRRT's essays published in 1983 or 1984 (C. Tolkien (ed.), _The monsters and the critics, and other essays_, Houghton Mifflin); however, a search of archive.org's borrowable copy of the same book fails to find the phrase.

Comment: @DanielHatton - None of the essays in that book are directly related to the legendarium. (Though there is a bit about Tolkien's invented languages in the last two essays.) There are three places where the phrase "sun and moon" appears, but none have anything to do with Middle-earth.

Comment: I cannot post an answer since the question contains multiple misunderstandings from secondary sources. The chronology, as I remember it, was like this: Arda was created; Melkor and the other Valar strove against each other; Melkor was imprisoned; the Elves awoke under the stars; Melkor was set free but did not behave as he promised and with Ungoliant he destroyed the Two Trees; two remaining fruits of the Trees were set in the sky as the Sun and the Moon. Before that there was no counting of days or years. After that the question is whether the "years" are our years, or 144 of our years. HTH

Comment: Addendum: All of that was in what is considered the First Age. The "Age of the Sun" was not distinct from the First Age; it was after the Sun was placed in the sky, The Second Age did not begin until after the War of Wrath and the founding of Númenor.

Comment: @Wastrel - There is an accounting of years starting with the planting of the two trees, known as the "Days of Bliss". There is also an accounting known as the "First Age" which starts from the awakening of the elves, and (back when Tolkien still had it that the Sun was only created after the destruction of the trees), there was an accounting known as the "Years of the Sun" which starts from the Sun. The First Age though starts with the awakening of the elves, not with the Sun. Please see the quotes in my answer.

Answer (score 14):

### Tolkien never uses the term "age(s) of the sun" in his writings

Difficult to prove a negative, but at least he doesn't use it anything that has been published, and easily searchable. Certainly nothing that predates that fan usage of the terms.

### Tolkien's "Ages" when given categories, are usually "Ages of the Children of Ilúvatar". (Though sometimes also "of Time" or "of the World") As such, the first age begins with the awakening of the elves.

> In those days, in the Year one thousand and fifty of the Valar, the Elves awoke in Kuiviénen and the First Age of the Children of Ilúvatar began.
> <sub>*Morgoth's Ring* - 'The Annals of Aman' - §10</sub>

> In the manuscript as it was originally written the Elder Days began with the Awakening of the Elves: 'Here begin the Elder Days, or the First Age of the Children of Iluvatar'
> <sub>*The War of the Jewels* - Christopher describing 'The Tale of Years'</sub>

> The First Age begins with the Awaking and ends with the Downfall of Angband.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - 'Generational Schemes'</sub>

### The chronologies that Tolkien writes which begin the years from the rising of the sun use unit labels like "Years of the Sun", and not "First Age". The chronologies which do use unit labels of First Age years all have the Awakening of the Elves in year one.

> First Age 1 - Quendi awake in the Spring (144 in number). Melian warned in a dream leaves Valinor and goes to Endor.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - 'Key Dates'</sub>

> Days of Bliss. End of Waiting Time. First Age begins. Awaking of Quendi (Spring).
> 1 - Awaking of Quendi (Spring).
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - 'Key Dates'</sub>

### Tolkien also was concerned with having all three ages be of comparable length, rather than the first age just being a few centuries.

> The Trees flower for 864 VY before Awaking = 124,416 [sun-]years. Quendi then awake in Spring of [VY] 865 (124,417 [YS]). “DB” still goes on, but Quendi start reckoning of First Age with Awaking.
> First Age must last somewhat longer than SA (= 3,441). Still be more regularly “duodecimal” (as mythological) up to Death of Trees and after! Say, 4,056 years.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - 'Key Dates'</sub>

### The events contemporary with the rising of the Sun have also been described by both Tolkien and Christopher as the "end" of the first age, not the beginning.

> [Quenya] was no longer a birth-tongue, but had become, as it were, an ‘Elvenlatin’, still used for ceremony, and for high matters of lore and song, by the High Elves, who had returned in exile to Middle-earth at the end of the First Age.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* Appendix F - Of the Elves</sub>

> The title of this second part, *The War of the Jewels*, is an expression that my father often used of the last six centuries of the First Age: the history of Beleriand after the return of Morgoth to Middle-earth and the coming of the Noldor, until its end.
> <sub>*The War of the Jewels* - Introduction</sub>

### So where does the term "Ages of the Sun" come from?

There are a couple of places that may be to blame here.

For one, Tolkien has been a lot less clear in his published works about where the first age started than where it ended. It can be inferred, but it's not obvious.

For another, there were some early chronology resources, such as the one included in Robert Foster's 1978 "The Complete Guide to Middle-earth", which began with the rising of the Sun. Foster himself never uses the term "ages of the sun", and is very clear to say that his chronology was only a part of the first age, the part that was easily quantifiable given the materials available at the time. But perhaps this could have contributed a bit to the confusion.

However, others of course were *a lot less* careful than Foster was. And I think it is fair to say that the blame is not at all on Foster or Tolkien here.

As best as I can tell, the first person, and also the most notable person, to use this term was David Day, in his 1979 book *A Tolkien Bestiary*.

Day uses the term "ages of the sun" a few times in the body of this book. (Minimizing these quotations as much as possible to avoid spreading any more of Day's misinformation than needed).

> the second [chart] is a closer view of the Ages of Sun ... for a detailed listing of events and incidents of the Second and Third Ages of the Sun, the reader must consult ...
> <sub>*A Tolkien Bestiary* - Intro</sub>

> In the first Age of the Sun the Werewolf race was bred.
> <sub>*A Tolkien Bestiary* - Wolves</sub>

Day also includes a chart in the book, full of made up terms for different time periods.

> [image]
> <sub>*A Tolkien Bestiary* - A Chronology of Middle-earth and the Undying Lands. (**PLEASE DO NOT RELY ON THIS OR ANYTHING ELSE FROM DAVID DAY**)</sub>

David Day of course is never satisfied with simply making up information once, but likes repeating this over and over again. His countless other books continue to use these terms over and over again. I singled out *A Tolkien Bestiary* because it seems to be the first published place. I will not be going through all his other books here.

Comment: This was my first time actually looking things up in David Days books, and they are indeed as horrible as people say they are.

Comment: @Glorfindel - "Kuiviénen" is not a typo.

Comment: Not at all difficult to prove a negative with (a) finite corpus of fiction, (b) which have been digitized, and (c) which you can search completely.

Comment: @Lexible - The part that actually is difficult is padding out a negative so that it takes up more space in an answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's written with a C in all books I have, but no doubt you have more ...

Comment: @Glorfindel see middle-period Qenya at https://www.elfdict.com/w/kuivieenen

Comment: A chronology with no actual years but also made-up names for various epochs.... smh, as the young people say.

Comment: @Glorfindel - Tolkien often has multiple ways that he spells names, especially in his unpublished material. In this particular place that I am quoting Tolkien spells it with a K. (I give the exact paragraph citation in case you want to look it up yourself.)

Comment: @DavidRoberts - Turns out I used the wrong chart. The one in the archive.org scan I was using was hard to read so I swapped it with one from a newer Day book. Just realized they were different so I've switched it back. But yeah, looks like Day didn't bother to remove any of his invented garbage from the chart, but just kept adding more.

Comment: OMG that chart is such a heap of pretentious fabrication.

Comment: @Glorfindel from History of Middle Earth vol.10 index:  Cuiviénen - see Kuiviénen.  vol.5 has just Kuiviénen.

Answer (score 3):

Though both these sites are fan made thus not actually official, your question is also about something that cannot be answered with a authoritative source so....

According to [LotR.Fandom](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/First_Age#Terminology):

> J.R.R. Tolkien does not give First Age dates in the Appendix B or in Quenta Silmarillion. In works such as The Annals of Aman, Tolkien measures the First Age with Years of the Valar (YV) and then Years of the Sun (YS).
>
> Robert Foster, among other Tolkienists, attempted to chronicle the First Age, using as convention the Years of the Sun as "First Age", keeping a format similar to the annals in Appendix B. For example, the twentieth Year of the Sun is referred to as I 20 or FA 20, though Foster admits that the definition YS 1 would be more accurate than FA 1. Unfortunately, this convention creates the ambiguation that FA 1 was the first year of the First Age marked as such by the first sunrise, leading to the term "Ages of the Sun", which does not appear in Tolkien's works.

and according to [Tolkien Gateway](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/First_Age) too it was Robert Foster and a group of Tolkienists who coined the term of first age.

Comment: Foster never says that his the first age begins with the rising of the sun. Under his entry for first age he says it probably either began "*with the completion of Arda or with the
awakening cf the Elves*". In his chronology of the first age, he does count the years from the sun, but lists 17 events in the first age that preceded that, and explicitly says that the 600 years he enumerates "*is not to say, of course, that the First Age lasted six hundred years; the Sleep of Yavanna alone may have endured for the equivalent of tens of thousands of Years of the Sun.*"

Comment: You should note that since the phrasing on Fandom and Tolkien Gateway is very similar ("Robert Foster among other Tolkienists attempted to chronicle the First Age; by convention these sources use the Years of the Sun as "First Age" keeping a format similar to Appendix B. For example the twentieth Year of the Sun is referred to as I 20 or F.A. 20"), it is a _near certainty_ one of these has used the other as a source text, or are adapting from a common source. So they aren't independent corroborating sources.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - It was added to Tolkien Gateway [in 2012](https://tolkiengateway.net/w/index.php?title=First_Age&diff=220613&oldid=212236) and to Fandom [in 2021](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/First_Age?diff=274293&oldid=272616). I agree that one of them is just copying the other, but it's pretty clear which one is copying which.

Comment: @ibid I assumed it was that direction, but I didn't care to check.

Comment: For the record, there is another, earlier, "First Age" chronicle in the Later Annals of Valinor (see HoME vol. 5).